# Show metadata of file with URL

Tags: swift, cocoa, interface-builder, metadata

I am building a macOS application and am using NSOpenPanel to get access to the system file structure so I can get to any file and import it to the app I am making. I am able to get the URL of a file, and the string of said URL, but I was wondering if there was a simple way to extract metadata of the file at the URL and display it in a textfield?

Comment: When you want to work with files, check [`FileManager`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager) first.

Comment: There is nothing in there about metadata though, unless I missed it?

Comment: What metadata are you referring to? Have you looked at the URL documentation?

Comment: Seems you have missed it

Comment: Yeah I have looked at the URL docs, and I did find anything with control f for "metadata". The metadata I am referring to is like "creator" "resolution" etc from files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `MDItem...` functions from the CoreServices framework:

```
import Foundation
import CoreServices

let path = someURL.path
if let mditem = MDItemCreate(nil, path as CFString),
   let mdnames = MDItemCopyAttributeNames(mditem),
   let mdattrs = MDItemCopyAttributes(mditem, mdnames) as? [String:Any] {
    print(mdattrs)
    print("Creator: \(mdattrs[kMDItemCreator as String] as? String ?? "Unknown")")
} else {
    print("Can't get attributes for \(path)")
}
```

For more details, see the [File Metadata](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/file_metadata) section of the Core Services framework.

Comment: Now this is exactly what I am looking for! One thing I am struggling to do with it is extract specific data out of this though. I can see all of the types of data I can pull, but how do I actually do it? When I initialise a variable to be a  kMDItemTitle, and then go to print this variable, it doesn't work. What am I missing here?

Comment: I show an example of getting the creator. Do the same for other `kMDItem...` values as needed. But note that not all files have values for all metadata.

Comment: But regardless won't it print "unknown"? I tried changing it to kMDItemTitle but it still printed "unknown". It will definitely have a title but it isn't wanting to work for me.

Comment: Do you have an alternative for iOS? The API only works on MacOS CMIIW